# GDB can't create a breakpoint

Tags: gdb, breakpoints

I am working on implementing a simple stack overflow, which I am examining with gdb. A problem I keep coming up with is gdb not accepting my breakpoints. My c code is quite simple:

```
void function(int a, int b, int c) {
   ...//stuff
}

void main() {
  int x;

  x = 0;
  function(1,2,3);
  x = 1;
  printf("%d\n",x);
}
```

And i'm using gcc -m32 -fno-stack-protector -o example3test example3test.c to complie it.

I have tried just setting a simple breakpoint on the line <+42> just to test if it works.

```
(gdb) disass main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x000005d1 <+0>:     lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
   0x000005d5 <+4>:     and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   0x000005d8 <+7>:     pushl  -0x4(%ecx)
   0x000005db <+10>:    push   %ebp
   0x000005dc <+11>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x000005de <+13>:    push   %ebx
   0x000005df <+14>:    push   %ecx
   0x000005e0 <+15>:    sub    $0x10,%esp
   0x000005e3 <+18>:    call   0x470 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx>
   0x000005e8 <+23>:    add    $0x1a18,%ebx
   0x000005ee <+29>:    movl   $0x0,-0xc(%ebp)
   0x000005f5 <+36>:    push   $0x3
   0x000005f7 <+38>:    push   $0x2
   0x000005f9 <+40>:    push   $0x1
   0x000005fb <+42>:    call   0x5a0 <function>
   0x00000600 <+47>:    add    $0xc,%esp
   0x00000603 <+50>:    movl   $0x1,-0xc(%ebp)
   0x0000060a <+57>:    sub    $0x8,%esp
   0x0000060d <+60>:    pushl  -0xc(%ebp)
   0x00000610 <+63>:    lea    -0x1950(%ebx),%eax
   0x00000616 <+69>:    push   %eax
   0x00000617 <+70>:    call   0x400 <printf@plt>
   0x0000061c <+75>:    add    $0x10,%esp
   0x0000061f <+78>:    nop
   0x00000620 <+79>:    lea    -0x8(%ebp),%esp
   0x00000623 <+82>:    pop    %ecx
   0x00000624 <+83>:    pop    %ebx
   0x00000625 <+84>:    pop    %ebp
   0x00000626 <+85>:    lea    -0x4(%ecx),%esp
   0x00000629 <+88>:    ret
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) break *0x000005fb
Breakpoint 1 at 0x5fb
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/jasmine/tutorials/smashingTheStackForFun/example3test
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x5fb
```

I'm lost as to why it won't accept this breakpoint. Most of the answers already on here involve not using the * or using wrong notation, from what I can see mine looks right, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm lost as to why it won't accept this breakpoint.

You have a position independent executable, which is relocated to a different address at runtime.

This will work:

```
(gdb) start
# GDB stops at main

(gdb) break *&main+42
(gdb) continue
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22491581/50617).

Comment: Wow, okay that worked, I was so confused because I had been already working on this in gdb beforehand and I had used break *0x.... which would work, and I couldn't figure it out why it wasn't working now.